# Converting String into ReactComponent

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-component

I know its weird use case but already im in the middle of PoC and stucked with below problem.

I have X jsx files in autoGenerated directory (which are transpiled from HTML using react-magic library). Now I need to dynamically load them into my react application depends on path. 
To be more clear look at code snippet.

```
<Route path="*" getComponent={(location, cb) => {
      const componentName = makeComponentName(location.pathname);

      $.get(`/autoGenerated/${componentName}.jsx`, (res) => {
        const element = React.createElement(res);
        cb(null, element);
      })
  }} />
</Route>
```

Element im downloading from server can be either pure JSX content as well as element with React.createClass etc. It's up to me how I transpile my html code.

What actually is the problem? I can not convert string downloaded from ajax call into actual component. I've also tried doing that on components side - I mean I had generalComponent, which inside download content via ajax (also getting string) and I was trying to pass this string somehow to render method.. it also didnt work.

Of course static loading all components are not in option cause there are hundreds if not thousands of them.

Do you have any clues?